# How to set node priority in Windows server 2016 Failover cluster

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2016, failovercluster

I have 4 Nodes and each node have 10 - 15 resources. so is there a way that we can set Node Priority like whenever a failover happens the resource is always failed over to priority 1 node.

Server: Windows Server 2016

Failover cluster manager: 10.0

Resource configuration version: 8.0

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the preferred owner setting in failover cluster. Follow the following steps.

- Open the *Failover Cluster Console* in one of the nodes
- Right click on the role that you want to provide high availability (Example VM - Properties)
- Select all nodes that you want in the failover cluster and make Node 1 up.